# Javascript failing calling from a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html page that is calling a Javascript function..

For some reason the JS function is not being called

```
<html>
    <body>
        function validateForm()
        {
            alter("Validate form")
            var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
            {
                alert("First name must be filled out");
            }
        <form name="myForm" onsubmit="validateForm()">
            First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </body>
```

Final js function..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm()
            {
                alter("Validate form")
                var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
                if (x==null || x=="")
                {
                    alert("First name must be filled out");

                }
            }
        </script>
        <body>
            <form name="myForm" onsubmit="validateForm()">
                First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

        </body>
```

Comment: You are missing the script tag !!

Comment: Learn to use a browser console! Either Chrome or Firefox!, it would have pointed out these errors to you much easier!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javascript functions need to be put in a `script` tag. As follows:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm() {
            alert("Validate form");
            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
            if (x == null || x == "") {
                alert("First name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();">First name:
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

---

### EDIT

Working fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5myKB/).

Comment: I fixed the script tag and ran the above script but still its the same problem..

Comment: @user1050619 You have misspelt `alert` on the second line - `alter("Validate form")` and are missing a closing curly brace `}` - have you since corrected these mistakes?

Comment: I have updated the final function above..

Comment: @user1050619 Also, put a `;` after the first alert. It's a good practice.

Comment: @user1050619 Check here -> http://jsfiddle.net/5myKB/

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your JavaScript in a script tag, also you spelt alert wrong the first time and the closing `}` for the function.

```
<script>
function validateForm()
    {
    alert("Validate form")
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("First name must be filled out");

      }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The function needs to be wrapped  in `<script>` tags, and you are missing a curly brace at the end of the script. Also "alert" is spelled wrong.

```
function validateForm()
{
alert("Validate form") // alert spelt wrong
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");

  }
} // newly added brace
```

Comment: Also 'alert' is spelled wrong